# I don't get the actual number of files in my directory. Where is the problem?

Tags: c++, file, visual-c++

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    bool x = true
int i = 0;
wchar_t* file = L"d:/tester/*.txt";
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;
hFind = FindFirstFile(file, &FindFileData); 
if( hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
    cout << "find failed\n";
}  else {
           while(x) {  
        i++;
        x = FindNextFile( hFind ,&FindFileData );
           }
   }

cout << "\nnumber of files in the directory : " << i << endl <<endl ;
  }
```

The output that i get is :

`find failed`

`number of files in the directory : 0`

Where i am going wrong ?  I want the number of .txt files to calculated in the directory.

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` return?

Answer (score 1):

You use invalid slashes in the path. In the Windows the back slashes are used '\' instead of '/'. Just to remind when putting the back slashe in the string it should be prepended with another one: "\\".

Comment: While it's indeed good practice to work with native paths, FindFirstFile does work with forward slashes as well.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.16 -> "Use forward slashes on all your filenames"

Comment: @phresnel : that applies to the Standard Library functions. The Microsoft CRT rewrites the slashes in pathnames _before_ passing them to `CreateFile`. Native functions should use native paths.

Comment: @MSalters Has this changed recently?  Historically (since MS-DOS 2.0), Microsoft OS's have accepted either `'/'` or `'\\'` indifferently as directory separators.  It was the libraries or utility programs which didn't accept the `'/'`.

Comment: Utilities interpreted /foo as an option, which is why they didn't support it in path names (Unix of course uses -foo for that). DOS indeed didn't bother. But under NT, DOS style paths are symbolic links instead. I don't think that the truely native paths (`\\?\Device...` support forward slashes at all. The `C:/foo/bar.txt` paths are resolved, and I believe that you can have some issues there. In particular, `":/tester/*.txt` cannot be resolved to a true native path due to the wildcard.

Comment: @MSalters: I see - Must say I disagree with Microsoft there; I'd say if the programming language in question uses a specific path-format, that should be considered native to the language (plus it would avoid backslash typery). Anyways, the <strike>law</strike> <strike>standard</strike> microsoft is harsh, but that's the them. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @phresnel : the C++ language does not use a specific path format, or even acknowledge the existance of paths at all.

Comment: @MSalters: not about paths specifically, but for include-names (h-char-sequence or q-char-sequence), see [lex.header], which forbids backslashes (windows), apostrophes (every major OS), /* (possible on any unixlike), and // (any major os) for both forms of #include, " for the "-form of include, and says in the footnote "sequences of characters that resemble escape sequences cause undefined behavior" // as for iostreams: You are right, I did not find any reference; still though, forward slashes are wider supported.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no txt files under d:/tester, FindFirstFile will return 0; apart from that, you have to loop FindNextFile until it returns 0 as well.

Comment: off course it's the same after looping: as long as FindFirstFile returns 0 you can't loop anyway since there's not a single file found. Did you follow cnicutar's advice and show the output of GetLastError() ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this code shall give you a listing of files in the directory(I had answered a Q long back & it works). You can tweak it to get count files of your choice.

The problem with your code is that the path being not recognized because of the single backlash as mentioned by @Eugene.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA search_data;

    memset(&search_data, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));

    HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile("c:\\*", &search_data);

    while(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout<<"\n"<<search_data.cFileName;

        if(FindNextFile(handle, &search_data) == FALSE)
           break;
    }

    //Close the handle after use or memory/resource leak
    FindClose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

Hth!

Comment: I have used single forward slash and it works for me , see my own answer

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
bool x = true;
int i = 0;
wchar_t* file = L"d:/testing/*.txt";
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hFind;
hFind = FindFirstFile(file, &FindFileData); 

if( hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
    i++;
    while ((x = FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData)) == TRUE)
     i++;   
}
cout << "number of files" << i << endl;
}
```

This Code works fine for me